# How to store data type text in key/value pair settings table

Tags: mysql, database-design, configuration, relational-database, entity-attribute-value

I was reading this discussion: [Using a Single Row configuration table in SQL Server database. Bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300356/using-a-single-row-configuration-table-in-sql-server-database-bad-idea/43540946)

But I didn't find the answer I was looking for regarding the text data type.

If I have a key/value pair settings table in the database, how would I store a text data type?

I don't want to add a field with the data type text because I guess this would be a performance issue.

I'm thinking that maybe I could have another table where I store the text and then link it together with an ID. That way there would be no bad effect on the main settings table.

Like so:

```
tblSettings
[id], [key], [valueChar], [valueInt], [valueDate], [valueFloat], [valueMeta]
1, 'template', null, null, null, null, 1

tblMeta
[id], [valueText]
1, '<html>....'
```

Would that be a good solution or is there a better one that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Edit your question and tag with the database you are using.  `text` is not a standard SQL type.

Comment: See the tag I added.