# Check constraint on bool column with EF Core and Postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'm using EF Core with Postgres. I want to create a "Configuration" table with [one row only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2300493/9971404), which means:

- adding bit column with default value
- adding check constraint to ensure column has that value
- adding unique constraint on that column

So I added a shadow column like this:

```cs
builder.ToTable(x => x.HasCheckConstraint("CK_Configuration_IsSingleRow", "IsSingleRow = false"));
builder.Property<bool>("IsSingleRow").HasDefaultValue(false).IsRequired();
builder.HasIndex("IsSingleRow").IsUnique();
```

But I get an error:

> Npgsql.PostgresException: **operator does not exist: boolean = integer**
> MessageText: operator does not exist: boolean = integer
> Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types.

I tried `IsSingleRow = true`, `IsSingleRow = 'true'`, `IsSingleRow = 1` and `IsSingleRow = '1'`.

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: About the shadow column workaround, you could also try `.HasCheckConstraint("CK_Configuration_IsSingleRow", "IsSingleRow"));` (it's already a `boolean`) or `.HasCheckConstraint("CK_Configuration_IsSingleRow", "IsSingleRow is true"));` or `.HasCheckConstraint("CK_Configuration_IsSingleRow", "IsSingleRow = 1::bool"));`. Directly on the db, only the `=1` is giving me an error: https://dbfiddle.uk/J5ahYQBt

Comment: @Zegarek Thanks for helping me sort out this issue, appreciate all the comments.

Comment: By the way, it's quite odd to have a bool property, and then a check constraint which enforces that it can only be true... What use is that property then, if it can never hold anything other than one value?

Comment: @ShayRojansky It's explained in the thread linked up top: it's one of a few tricks to prevent insertion of any rows beyond the first one.

Comment: Some config belongs in `appsettings.json` but some belongs in the database. I find this trick to be very useful, and it's working like a charm thank to you guys... thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL folds unquoted identifiers to lower-case; that means you need to quote the column name in your check constraint SQL:

```cs
builder.ToTable(x => x.HasCheckConstraint("CK_Configuration_IsSingleRow", "\"IsSingleRow\" = true"));
```

You should also be able to omit the `= true`, since your IsSingleRow column is already a boolean.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77542991/2

Comment: In a last revision of the question I thought it was a quoting problem and tried every conceivable quoting alternative, without success. Now it works, and I'm dumbfounded why it didn't work before. Maybe I also quoted the strings in Property and HasIndex. Regardless, thanks for your advice, it works well now!

Comment: @lonix I'm equally puzzled as to what the problem *actually* was and what really solved it, because it's not this; that's what you tried in rev2. If you have the time to properly retrace your steps to preproduce the problem, pinpoint the issue and figure out what lead up to it and what ended up fixing it, this might be a very valuable thread to anyone struggling with a similar "anomaly". Otherwise, this thread is pretty much an "it acted weird but it somehow solved itself", and on top that, an observation which was already the starting point of the question is marked as the solution.